# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: <binding> 'BillServicePortBinding' already defined

Tags: php, soap

Tengo este problema al tratar de consumir un *webservice* `wsdl`:

El código en `php` que estoy realizando para consumir el servicio web es el siguiente:

```
$wsdlURL = 'https://e-factura.sunat.gob.pe/ol-ti-itcpfegem/billService?wsdl';
$client  = new SoapClient($wsdlURL, array('trace' => true));
print_r($client);
```

Este es el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:  'BillServicePortBinding' already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\invoicePHP\xmlFactura.php:45 Stack trace

**¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?**

Comment: Que versión estás usando?

Comment: Las imágenes pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta.

Comment: Mariano acabo de colocar el error en texto, por favor ojala puedas ayudarme.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema en producción. En beta funciona bien

Answer (score 1):

Segun [esta](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45282) página oficial de PHP, es un bug desde la versión 5.*

Lo que recomiendan es usa la implementación **Pear SOAP**

http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que php no admite doble "namespace" cosa que si hace java y c#.
Por suerte tiene una solución fácil pero igual hay que tomarla con cuidado: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342419/php-soapclient-problems-with-distributed-wsdl-file